# Find the coordinates of the stationary points of $e^x +ye^{-x} = 2e^2$.

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, implicit-differentiation

> Find the coordinates of the stationary points of $e^x +ye^{-x} = 2e^2$.

So I have differentiated this implicitly, which I think is correct but I'm then unsure how I'd actually solve the equation.

$$\frac d {dx}(e^x) + \frac d {dx}(ye^{-x}) = \frac d {dx} (2e^2)$$

$$\frac d {dx}(e^x) = e^x\quad \frac d {dx}(ye^{-x})=e^{-x}\frac {dy} {dx} - ye^{-x} \quad \frac d {dx}(2e^2)$$

Thus $$e^x +e{-x}\frac{dy}{dx} -ye^{-x}=1$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1-e^{-x} + ye^{-x}}{e^{-x}}$$
At the stationary point $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ so
$$0=1-e^{x} +ye^{-x}$$
I then multiplied through by $e^x$ and rearranged to get
$$y = e^{2x} -e^x$$

Where do I go from here, If I've done everything right up to this stage?

Comment: You may write the equation as $(e^x-e^2)^2=e^2-y$.  From here $y=e^2$ and $x=2$.

Comment: The equation $e^x+y e^{-x}=2e^2$ defines a set $S$ (a curve) in the $(x,y)$-plane. What is your definition of the *stationary points" of $S$ ?

Comment: The point at which the gradient of the curve is 0

Comment: By “gradient” do you mean the slope of the tangent to the curve, or $\nabla(e^x+ye^{-x})$? It seems to be the former.

Comment: The gradient of the tangent at that point. The definition of what gradient is